# blog name in url instead of id in meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I've a blog and I want the blog post name instead of blog id in how to do this

I want the url like `mysite.com/firs-post` not like `mysite.com/_id`

code

```
Router.map("blogpost",{
     path:"/blog/:slug",
     template:"singlepost",
     data:function(){
         return blog.findOne({});//want to return single blog
     }
});
```

the blog post name may be duplicate,

```
I want to redirect to particular blog post without the id in url
```

Comment: You want to redirect on a template event? click on one link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I end up creating a link using the blog name and id of the record(last 5 letters)

Like

`post-name-xh45d`

Answer (score 1):

One idea could be to have a link on the template like for example:

```
<a href="/blog_post_name"></a>
```

Now in iron:router

```
 Router.map("blogpost",{
     path:"/blog/:slug",
     template:"singlepost",
     waitOn: function () {
         return [Meteor.subscribe('blog')];
     },
     data: function(){
         return blog.findOne({name: this.params.slug});//want to return single blog
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thought of it, but when we refresh the page or when user goes to particular url from another site it will not work

Comment: I want something like hiding the id kind of hack :)

Comment: this will not work because as I said in the question, there may be duplicate blog titles,so when we do findOne it returns the first record it found